# Capture between pattern of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck trying to capture a structure like this:

```
1:1 wefeff qwefejä qwefjk
dfjdf 10:2 jdskjdksdjö
12:1 qwe qwe: qwertyå
```

I would want to match everything between the digits, followed by a colon, followed by another set of digits. So the expected output would be:

```
match 1 = 1:1 wefeff qwefejä qwefjk dfjdf
match 2 = 10:2 jdskjdksdjö
match 3 = 12:1 qwe qwe: qwertyå
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
\d+\:\d+.+
```

But that fails if there are word characters spanning two lines.

I'm using a javascript based regex engine.

Comment: Something like  `(?s)\d+:\d+(?:(?!\d+:\d).)*` should work.

Comment: The `.` is any character except new lines, unless the `s` modifier is set.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew That did work! Do you want to make an answer out of it?  A brief explanation would be greatly appreciated if you have the time!

Comment: @Antti: I posted the regex solution adjust for JavaScript since the tag was added after my initial comment. I also added an unrolled regex version that will work regardless of modifiers used with the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex based on a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
/\d+:\d+(?:(?!\d+:\d)[\s\S])*/g
```

The `\d+:\d+` part will match one or more digits, a colon, one or more digits and `(?:(?!\d+:\d)[\s\S])*`  will match any char, zero or more occurrences, that do not start a sequence of one or more digits followed with a colon and a digit. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFV0Xm/1).

As the tempered greedy token is a resource consuming construct, you can [unroll it](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) into a more efficient pattern like

```
/\d+:\d+\D*(?:\d(?!\d*:\d)\D*)*/g
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifd4nD/1).

Now, the `()` is turned into a pattern that matches strings *linearly*:

- `\D*`  - 0+ non-digit symbols
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching zero or more sequences of:

  - `\d` - a digit that is...
  - `(?!\d*:\d)` - not followed with 0+ digits, `:` and a digit
  - `\D*` - 0+ non-digit symbols
- `)*` - end of the non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

you can use or not the ñ-Ñ, but you should be ok this way

```
\d+?:\d+? [a-zñA-ZÑ ]*
```

Edited:

If you want to include the break lines, you can add the \n or \r to the set,

```
\d+?:\d+? [a-zñA-ZÑ\n ]*
\d+?:\d+? [a-zñA-ZÑ\r ]*
```

Give it a try ! also tested in https://regex101.com/

for more chars:
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*)(+=._-]+$

Comment: Doesnt' capture "dfjdf"

Comment: Now the problem is that it stop at special characters in the text like : and ä, I'll edit my question to contain  some special characters as well

Comment: you have the list of the special chars tha could be there ? when you have to add those to a regex, usually you use a set, this is the most accurate, but "short" used set of chars:

^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$